# How to show a picture of the link in user's feed when commenting on some URL on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, feed, image, comments

So when the user comments on some link, I want a picture of that link to show up on his feed alongside the link itself. Right now only the comment text and the link shows up on the feed, no pic is shown. Any ideas how to do that? Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you control the site that is being linked to, make sure the document has [Open Graph tags](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/), especially og:image.

For example on a rage face site [this document](http://www.memeface.com/pic/technique_addition_game) has the body tag:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.memeface.com/pic/technique_addition_game.jpg"/>
```

When someone posts a link to this site on Facebook, FB fetches the document and looks for these tags.